# Get element by key with Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I've been trying to retrieve an element from my Firebase database using its key. I have a class User and users are present in database.

[image: 1]

I want to retrieve an object user using its key with this method :

```
public User getConnectedUserByUId(final String uid){
    DatabaseReference database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    DatabaseReference ref = database.child("users");
    final List<User> connectedUser= new ArrayList<User>();
    ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot item: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                if (item.getKey()==uid)
                {
                    User user= dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
                    connectedUser.add(user);
                }

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }

    });
    return connectedUser.get(0);
}
```

but it returns an empty list every time.

Comment: Use `item.getKey().equals(uid)` instead.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is here:

```
if (item.getKey()==uid)
```

since you are comparing 2 `String` in java **you have to use** the method 
[`string.equals(Object other)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals-java.lang.Object-) not the `==` operator.

Moreover, since you know the key of the data in Firebase you can use it to get the reference without cycling all children.
Something like:

```
DatabaseReference database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference ref = database.child("users").child(uid);
```

Comment: even if he solves it like you suggest, it will always return an empty list: synchronous call to an asynchronous data fetch

Answer (score 0):

Here you try to check a very specific ID only on changed data. Instead, try using a Firebase Query with `filterByKey` and not using your own function to achieve that. Here's sample code that I would use to try to replace your function:

```
DatabaseReference database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference ref = database.child("users");
Query connectedUser = ref.equalTo(uid);
connectedUser.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            // TODO: handle the post here
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        // Getting Post failed, log a message
        Log.w(TAG, "loadPost:onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
        // ...
    }
});
```

As specified in the Firebase documentation here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#filtering_data

Comment: dude, what are you talking about? There is no `filterByKey`, perhaps you mean `orderByKey` + `equalTo`, and this would still be a bad suggestion because it would be a useless overkill. If you have the key, just use it in composing the path

Answer (score 0):

in the line : `User user= dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);`
you have to put : `User user= item.getValue(User.class);`
and you have to check the id after you get the user:

```
if (user.getKey()==uid){
connectedUser.add(user);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 mistakes and a minor issue:

- you are using `==` to compare two `String` objects. In java, this is true only if they are the same reference. Use `equals` instead.
- `addValueEventListener` only adds a listener that gets invoked once after you add it and then every time something changes in the value you are listening to: this is an asynchronous behaviour. You are trying to get data synchronously instead. Please read something about this.
- you are fetching useless data: you only need an object but you are fetching tons of them. Please consider to use the closest reference you can to the data you are fetching.

So, in conclusion, here's some code. I'd like to point out right now that forcing synchronous acquisition of naturaly asynchronous data is a bad practice. Nevertheless, here's a solution:

```
public User getConnectedUserByUId(final String uid){
    DatabaseReference database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    DatabaseReference ref = database.child("users").child(uid);
    Semaphore sem = new Semaphore(0);
    User[] array = new User[1];
    ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot item: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                if (item.getKey()==uid)
                {
                    User user= dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
                    array[0] = user;
                }

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }

    });
    try
        {
        sem.tryAcquire(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        }
    catch (Exception ignored)
        {
        }
    return array[0];
}
```

EDIT: I've just seen that this post is very old. I'm not sure how I ended up here.

Comment: Why to use timeout of 10 sec here. Its bad to slow the server